# How to disable select (read) statements from being recorded in the mysql general log table?

Tags: mysql

I have enabled mysql general log and set the log destination to mysql table (general_log) by running the following commands.

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
```

The table is growing too fast now (which i don't like) but most of the query that are logged are select(read) statements. I am more interested with only update, insert and delete. Is it possible then to make the select staments to be excempted from being logged into this table (Allow only CUD  to be logged from  CRUD)? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well it seems there is no option. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/log-destinations.html

You cannot even run a scheduled cronjob to clear out `select` queries from the table. You can change the Log table engine to MyISAM. It will improve storage performance.

Comment: Can i write  an EVENT scheduler to perform delelete on all rows with select statements instead? @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: If you refer the documentation link (in my previous comment), it clearly says that: "INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE cannot be used on a log table. These operations are permitted only internally to the server itself"